# WordPress > microsites use main site's menu (same domain, multiple subdirectories, multiple WP installs)

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a main site at site.com and several subdirectory "microsites" at site1.site.com, site2.site.com, etc. These are all on the same server.

Each site is set up in its own folder under public_html and each with its own separate wordpress install.

I'd like for each microsite to share the same top level menu (the page's menu) with the main site (I want the microsites to all use the main site's page menu).

I'm sure there are several approaches and I'd like to ask you for a few ideas.

As an aside, would the new WordPress 3.0 beta would make this simpler to do (since it combines wordpress MU into the main wordpress core)?

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably just use symbolic links for this.

Put your shared files in another directory (/public_html/shared) and have the menu files for each sub-site be a symbolic link to the shared menu file.

Comment: I don't really want to do this for the obvious downsides of having to edit multiple sites whenever something changes on the main site. If I'm understanding you correctly.

Comment: @Scott - Using a link should avoid exactly that.  You would have a single file with multiple links going to it.  Editing that shared file would in effect change the file in all the locations that point to it.

Comment: Thanks Eric. I suppose I need to better understand exactly what a "symbolic link" is and how to create one. I assumed you were just talking about a standard a href link. Are you talking about .shtml or includes?

Comment: @Scott - it's actually something in the UNIX filesystem.  Think of it like a "Shortcut" file in windows, except that it behaves just like it was the actual file itself.  See here: http://kb.iu.edu/data/abbe.html